# How to license my closed source & freeware (donation ware) - using creative commons?

Tags: licensing, copyright, free-software, creative-commons

After doing a bit of research about licensing my free software, I reached this:

Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 3.0 Unported - http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/

---

how do I include it in my software or website ?

---

going here: https://creativecommons.org/choose/

I see the text that I should include:

> This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 3.0 Unported License. To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/.

Answer (score 6):

[Creative Commons licenses should not be used for software](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_apply_a_Creative_Commons_license_to_software.3F). From the FAQ:

> ## Can I apply a Creative Commons license to software?
>
> We do not recommend it. Creative Commons licenses should not be used for software. We strongly encourage you to use one of the very good software licenses which are already available. We recommend considering licenses made available by the [Free Software Foundation](http://www.fsf.org/) or listed at the [Open Source Initiative](http://www.opensource.org/). Unlike our licenses, which do not make mention of source or object code, these existing licenses were designed specifically for use with software. Furthermore, our licenses are [not compatible with the GPL](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/gpl-compatible.html), the most frequently used free software license.
>
> Note that the CC0 Public Domain Dedication **is** GPL-compatible and acceptable for software. For details, [see the relevant CC0 FAQ entry](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F).